# my php if statement doesn't work

Tags: php, if-statement, header

This is my first time asking a question in this website so please bear with me. I got a script from another website for testing internet connection speed and added if else statement. If the speed is more than 500, it will redirect to a specific page. For some reasons, I can't make it to work. I have added the `ob_start();` before the `<html>` tag and also added `ob_end_flush();` after the `</html>` tag. I have added the code below in between my body tags.

```
$kb=512;
flush();
$time = explode(" ",microtime());
$start = $time[0] + $time[1];

for($x=0;$x<$kb;$x++){
    echo str_pad('', 1024, '');
    flush();
}
$time = explode(" ",microtime());
$finish = $time[0] + $time[1];
$deltat = $finish - $start;
$intspeed = round($kb / $deltat, 0);
echo $intspeed; //just to check if $intspeed has a value

if ($intspeed > 500) {
  header("Location: test.php"); 
  exit();
} else  {
  header('Location: falcons/index.php');
  exit();   
}
```

Comment: You cannot print anything on the screen (use `echo`) before sending custom headers. You're echoing something on the screen, and then sending the redirect headers. thats the problem. remove the echo.

Comment: Humorously, the `echo $intspeed` will prevent the redirect

Comment: I'm pretty sure output buffering gets around that... of course, only if that code is between the `ob_start()` and `ob_end_flush()` the OP says he uses, rather than before or after.

Comment: So long as `ob_start` appears before *any* output, including whitespace, your `echo` shouldn't be affecting your ability to modify headers.

Comment: @Filap, Can you post all of your code, please.

Comment: that was fast! i just want to thank you all for the replies. Stackoverflow rocks! I will try all the response that I've got. Again, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `flush();` calls. Also, ensure that this code is between `ob_start()` and `ob_end_flush()`, not before or after (and also that nothing else is output before this code).

```
$kb=512;

$time = explode(" ",microtime());
$start = $time[0] + $time[1];

for($x=0;$x<$kb;$x++){
    echo str_pad('', 1024, '');
}
$time = explode(" ",microtime());
$finish = $time[0] + $time[1];
$deltat = $finish - $start;
$intspeed = round($kb / $deltat, 0);
echo $intspeed; //just to check if $intspeed has a value

if ($intspeed > 500) {
  header("Location: test.php"); 
  exit();
} else  {
  header('Location: falcons/index.php');
  exit();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only redirect via header() if output has not started yet. If there is already non header output (like in your for loop), setting the "Location" header has no effect.

I recommend using [`headers_sent()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php) before setting a "Location" header and have a fallback in case some debug information or something else already started output.

Comment: thank you. It works now! i have to remove the echo and the flush().